# Using the naturemag style in latex

Tags: natbib

Apologies for the short question. I'd like to know how to set up the naturemag.bst style for natbib. Should it look something like this:

`\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} \bibliographystyle{naturemag}`

I ran into issues with the compiler telling me I can't use author year despite this being numerical.

Comment: As always on this site, you are more likely to get help if you provide a full (but minimal) self contained example others can copy and test on their own. Here we have to provide a full document and bibliography.

Comment: My question doesn't require testing. I'm just asking if that's how you set it up

Comment: What you are doing is correct with the information you give us, but documentclass and other packages can affect the result, so you are not helping us much.

Comment: If it wasn't clear from my question, I am in the process of establishing my bibliography, hence why I asked if that was the correct setup. Thanks

Comment: And you are saying you get an error. Not at all clear what you wanted help with

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide the answers to desire, I'm not at my computer

Comment: It said my bibliography isn't compatible with author year citations despite me using numerical

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Yes, and package and class can alter the behaviour of natbib, thus why we always ask for something we can test independently of your setup.

Comment: BTW a simple article doc and a sample bib, you line gives no error on my TeXLive 2019